# Linking wordpress custom bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to link my WordPress Stylesheet to child theme at different directory/sub folder, it doesn't seems to work. Below are the code where I place it at `functions.php`

```
function theme_add_bootstrap()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/custom.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

I try putting @import statement inside style.css, it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
function theme_add_bootstrap()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

Remember that `get_template_directory_uri()` will give you directory uri path with no `/`. SO you need to add `/` after this function.

Hope this will work for you.